# Polyakov action with Kalb-Ramond field defined globally?

Tags: differential-geometry, string-theory, tensor-calculus, topology

In string theory, with the addition of the anti-symmetric $B$-field, the Polyakov action takes the form:
$$S=\frac{1}{4 \pi \alpha^{'}} \int_{\sum}d \sigma d \tau (\cdots + \epsilon^{\alpha \beta} B_{\mu \nu} \partial_{\alpha} X^{\mu} \partial_{\beta} X^{\nu} + \cdots).$$
Now the $B$-field is a locally defined 2-form, that is not necessarily globally defined, however the associated $H$-flux given by $H=dB$ is, and the $B$-field transforms as higher dimensional connection form, known as a gerbe.

I don't know how to make sense of the above integral given the $B$-field is only locally defined, but the integral goes over all of the worldsheet. How can one make sense of a globally defined integral over locally defined objects, where these objects don't transform in the required way (they transform as gerbes not tensors) for the integral to make global sense.?

Comment: What do you mean say that B-field transform as gerbes? B-field is Lorentz tensor in indeces $\mu, \nu$ and worldsheet scalar .

Comment: this is a good question. see Alvarez, O., https://inspirehep.net/record/206164?ln=en

Answer (score 1):

This $B$-term is equivalent to the $n\Gamma$ term in [WZW sigma models](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0550321383900639?via%3Dihub). You can think of this integral as a 3-dimensional integral of $H$ in $V$, where $\partial V=\Sigma$, being $\Sigma$ the worldsheet

$$
\oint_{\Sigma} B = \int_{V} H 
$$

since $H$ is globally defined all your worries should disappear. Dirac quantization for the NS-NS fluxes guarantee that physics will not be sensitive to how you extend the worldsheet fields from $\Sigma$ to $V$.